# Batch File Not Accepting Parameter in the form of %1, %2

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a simple script that does ftp uploading, the key thing is that I want to pass parameters such as host name, username, password etc into the `bat` file.

This is my script

```
@ftp -i -s:"%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
open %1
%2
%3
!:--- FTP commands below here ---
lcd "%4"
cd  %5
binary
put "%6"
disconnect
bye
```

Now, when I call the script from command line and pass in the `%1`, `%2` ... the `%1`, `%2` content won't get replaced by my command line parameters. This is my command line:

```
ftp.bat "first" "second" "third" "forth" "five" "six"
```

Instead of  `%1` becomes `first`, `%2` becomes `second` and so on, the `%1` remains `%1`, so essentially I am opening a ftp side with the name `%1` which is completely nonsensical.

Anything I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

That's because, at the point where you're actually processing the file, it's not a batch script at all.

It's an FTP script, which does not do any of that fancy substitution.

You can get your desired effect with a temporary file (based on the original file to avoid clashes) thus:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
set tmpfl=%~f0.tmp
echo>"%tmpfl%" open %1
echo>>"%tmpfl%" %2
echo>>"%tmpfl%" %3
echo>>"%tmpfl%" lcd "%4"
echo>>"%tmpfl%" cd %5
echo>>"%tmpfl%" binary
echo>>"%tmpfl%" put "%6"
echo>>"%tmpfl%" disconnect
echo>>"%tmpfl%" bye
type "%tmpfl%" && rem ftp -i -s:"%tmpfl%"
del /q "%tmpfl%"
endlocal
```

The `type` line is in there for debugging. When you're happy with the script, change:

```
type "%tmpfl%" && rem ftp -i -s:"%tmpfl%"
```

to:

```
ftp -i -s:"%tmpfl%"
```

Comment: I'm not too sure your last command is correct; although from `type "%tmpfl%" && rem ftp -i -s:"%tmpfl%"` I can see that I got everything right, but when I switch to `ftp -i -s:"%tmpfl%"`, the username (which is `%2`) becomes `%1`, which is the ftp address. So I got a weird message saying that 
**User (ftp.myhost.com:(none)): open "ftp.myhost.com"**. Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're passing the file in question to the ftp as a set of commands with the -s switch - "%~f0" expands to be the fully qualified file name of the batch file.  As a result the ftp client is parsing the file verbatim, it doesn't replace %1, %2, etc with the parameters.  That is done by the batch file handler, not the ftp client.

What you can try is writing a temporary file using "echo open %1 > temp.txt", etc, and then use that as an input to the ftp client.

The following appears to work well enough on my system:

```
echo open %1 > temp1.txt
echo %2 >> temp1.txt
echo %3 >> temp1.txt
rem !:--- FTP commands below here ---
echo lcd "%4" >> temp1.txt
echo cd  %5 >> temp1.txt
echo binary >> temp1.txt
echo put "%6" >> temp1.txt
echo disconnect >> temp1.txt
echo bye >> temp1.txt
@call ftp -i -s:"temp1.txt"&GOTO:EOF
```

Comment: Hopefully the example I added helps.

Comment: ah, I got an Access denied problem, most probably because my script has no right to `open` the `temp1.txt`.

Comment: I've made slight modification to the above script; namely instead of writing to a physical file, I write to a temporary file, but the problem I get is the same as the @paxdiablo's answer; the username becomes the ftp host name. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I don't know whether that's an artifact of the temporary file, the ftp server, the operating system or what, but I can't reproduce that.  When I ran a batch file containing the above verbatim, I connect to the ftp site and get prompted "331 Password required for username" by running "test ftp.myisp.com username password" (details redacted).